# Pentaho spoon:insert/update does DROP COLUMN?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I am doing insert/update step (text file to DB) on spoon and I have a question.
Suppose that in my text file I have 10 columns and in my DB I have 18, because 8 columns will be completed from another text file later.

On insert/update step, I chose a key to look up the value (which is `client_id`, for example) and on `"Update fields"`, I did mappings for those 10 columns. When I checked SQL query, I saw those 8 columns will be dropped.
But I want to keep them. Any solution for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Insert/Update step will NOT drop columns when run normally.

The SQL button inspects the table and suggests changes based on the fields you specified in the step. It's only a convenience for quick ETL development, for example when sending rows from text files to staging table using a Table Output step. It only drops columns if you execute the script it generates. Don't do that and your columns will be perfectly safe!